# Date Format In SSIS Derived Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have 2 questions, I have a text file with all my data, in the text file I have for example `Sply_DT` and `Imprt_DT`.

For `Sply_Dt` I have to create `getdate()` and I have it formatted as `2012-10-25 12:04:16.09900000` using `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(DT_DBDATE)GETDATE()` but I want it formatted as `MM-DD-YY`.

And for `Impt_DT`, it's in the `5/16/2011` format in dataviewer but when I placed it into a table it looks like `2011-05-16 00:00:00.000` and I want it in `MM-DD-YY` format.

Comment: What datatype are the columns in your database?

Comment: This is a presentation issue. SQL Server stores the datetime. How the date is formatted upon presentation is up to the app/report returning the data to the end user. SSIS cannot change how SQL Server stores the datetime or formats the datetime in query results. See http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/ for different datetime conversions which you can use to format the datetime before presenting it to the end user.

Comment: To clarify brian's comment, SQL Server stores `datetime` values as binary values, not as text. That is the reason that they have no format of their own. Since you're using SQL Server 2008, you might want to look at the `date` date type instead if the time portion is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some confusion about the [datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) data type. It does not care whether your locale is US (mm/dd/yyyy), Japan (yy/mm/dd) or the UK (dd/mm/yyyy), it will always be stored in the internal format.

If you don't like the default presentation, you can investigate [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and perhaps that makes sense for your query.

You can also apply the appropriate CONVERT format when you are querying the data to make it in your intended format.

```
DECLARE @datevar datetime = '2012-10-25'
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), @datevar, 10) AS YourFomat, @datevar AS defaultFormat
```

If I have misunderstood your question, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do it using the Derived Column component is simply like the following (for MM-DD-YY format):

LEN((DT_WSTR, 2)MONTH(GETDATE())) == 1 ? "0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)MONTH(GETDATE())) : (DT_WSTR, 2)MONTH(GETDATE())) + "-" + LEN((DT_WSTR, 2)DAY(GETDATE())) == 1 ? "0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DAY(GETDATE())) : (DT_WSTR, 2)DAY(GETDATE())) + "-" + RIGHT((DT_WSTR, 2)YEAR(GETDATE()), 2)

Comment: This would be fine if he was storing this in a string in the table, but he is pulling this from the sql table in a datetime format on presentation and it is in the default date format.

Comment: He marked it as SSIS-data-transformations so I provided him with an SSIS-friendly solution.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it you're aiming to alter the datetime format of data coming from the text file. I recommend you use a derived column transform in a data flow task to either add a column or replace the existing column, then you can use more common .NET date operators and format strings within the derived column to first parse the date, then to convert it to a string with the given format. If that does not work, you can instead use a script component in the data flow task to do what I described, in which case you have access to .NET to perform your modifications.

Comment: He is storing this in a SQL table, so it is stored internally in a numeric format and presented differently based upon settings.  .Net date operators don't even come into play in the presentation from SQL.